# Issue setting z-index and class via php

Tags: php, html, css, if-statement, echo

I have a bit of php code that sets the z-index and class of different tabs options within my menu in a header file. The header file is included into every page, then this code will determine what tab is active so the z index and css can be changed. My problem is that this code, no matter what $url equals, gives the home tab a z-index of 1000 and a class of "active tab". It seems to me like I have everything right in my if statement, does anyone know why It wont detect say, documentation.php and apply the 1000 z-index to this?

```
<?php

  $zi_home = "10";
  $zi_ss = "10";
  $zi_tes = "10";
  $zi_order = "10";
  $zi_con = "10";

  $tab_home = "inactive-tab";
  $tab_ss = "inactive-tab";
  $tab_tes = "inactive-tab";
  $tab_order = "inactive-tab";
  $tab_con = "inactive-tab";

    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

  if ($url = "/index.php") {
         $zi_home = "1000";
         $tab_home = "active-tab";
    } elseif ($url = "/documentation.php") {
         $zi_ss = "1000";
         $tab_ss = "active-tab";
    } elseif ($url = "/order.php") {
         $zi_tes = "1000";
         $tab_tes = "active-tab";
    } elseif ($url = "/about.php") {
         $zi_order = "1000";
         $tab_order = "active-tab";
    } elseif ($url = "/contactus.php") {
         $zi_con = "1000";
         $tab_con = "active-tab";
 }    

?>
```

header.php file snippet:

```
        <div class="<? echo $tab_home; ?>" style="z-index: <? echo $zi_home; ?>;">
            <a href = "index.php">Home</a>
        </div>

        <div class="<? echo $tab_ss; ?>" style="z-index: <? echo $zi_ss; ?>;">
            <a href = "documentation.php">Documentation</a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used = instead of ==. If you change those out it looks like it will work. Should be:

```
if ($url == "/index.php") {
     $zi_home = "1000";
     $tab_home = "active-tab";
} elseif ($url == "/documentation.php") {
     $zi_ss = "1000";
     $tab_ss = "active-tab";
} elseif ($url == "/order.php") {
     $zi_tes = "1000";
     $tab_tes = "active-tab";
} elseif ($url == "/about.php") {
     $zi_order = "1000";
     $tab_order = "active-tab";
} elseif ($url == "/contactus.php") {
     $zi_con = "1000";
     $tab_con = "active-tab";
}
```